# How can I use bash variables in .tmux.conf?

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm trying to write my own `.tmux.config` file and have managed to get most of it working (the file is quite simple). The intention is to have a minicom session running on the right side, whilst simultaneously saving the communication into a file. There is one problem. I define a `UART_LOGFILE_NAME` variable in my `.bashrc` file and export it, however, tmux still returns *invalid environment variable*. Is there something I'm missing?

my `.tmux.conf` file looks somewhat like this:

```
new-session -s serial -n console

split-window -h -l 30%
send-keys "sudo minicom rasp.serial -C ${UART_LOGFILE_NAME}"

split-window -v -l 10%
```

I can't find anything relevant in tmux manual entry except for the **GLOBAL AND SESSION ENVIRONMENT**. Also, sice I'm using the `send-keys` command I thought that the `.bash_profile` and therefore `.bashrc` files have been sourced before the minicom is launched (I have already managed to get the minicom running without logging and all panes have the `UART_LOGFILE_NAME` variable correctly defined after when I run tmux without logging of minicom session).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe try sourcing the config file?

Comment: @Jetchisel Can you be more specific? The `.tmux.conf` file is sourced automatically. Do you mean explicitly sourcing `.bashrc` using for example `send-keys`? Thanks